# Pushing objects into a hash inside a loop

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to achieve the following JSON results:

```
 {
    "movie" =>
             [{
               "title": "Thor",
               "year" : 2011,
             },
             {
               "title": "Iron Man",
               "year" : 2008,
             }],
     "tv" =>  
             [{
               "title": "Parks and Recreation"
               "year": 2009
             },
             {
               "title": "Friends"
               "year": 1994
             }]
  }
```

With JavaScript, I would loop through my results and do something like:

```
results['movie'].push(item);
results['tv'].push(item);
```

With Ruby code, the farthest I've gone is this:

```
@results = Hash.new
results['Search'].each do |r|
  if r['Type'] == 'movie'
    @results['movie'] << {
        'title' => r['Title'],
        'year' => r['Year']
    }
  elsif r['Type'] == 'series'
    @results['tv'] << {
        'title' => r['Title'],
        'year' => r['Year']
    }
  end
end
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please show the result (Ruby object) you want for your example.

Comment: So, what do you suppose the value of `@results['movie']` is when you first try to push to it? Also, what error are you getting? No method?

Comment: @jvillian, I do get results, but it's only giving me the last item in the loop, I want all of the items

Comment: @CarySwoveland the results I wanted is the JSON object structure I put above.

Comment: I misunderstood. Presumably, `results` (not `@results`) is a hash. What is it?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, sorry for the naming confusion, `results` is the set of results coming from an API I made a request to. `@results` is the hash I want to re-arrange the data into

Comment: "the farthest I've gone is this" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem has to do with the initialization of your hash. The `movie` and `tv` keys aren't currently an array. You can initialize your hash like this:

```
@results = { 'movie' => [], 'tv' => [] }
```

Here's how it looks with the rest of your code:

```
@results = { 'movie' => [], 'tv' => [] }
results['Search'].each do |r|
  if r['Type'] == 'movie'
    @results['movie'] << {
        'title' => r['Title'],
        'year' => r['Year']
    }
  elsif r['Type'] == 'series'
    @results['tv'] << {
        'title' => r['Title'],
        'year' => r['Year']
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: You are better off writing `@results = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = []}` to make it more general. If, for example, `@results` does not have a key `'movie'`, `@results['movie']` in `@results['movie'] << {  'title' => r['Title'], 'year' => r['Year']` will be set to an empty array before `<< {  'title' => r['Title'], 'year' => r['Year'] }` is executed.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's a good point. Making it general is only useful if this code aims to serve a use case more general than what the OP needs, however.

Comment: I agree, provided the crystal ball has concluded that the hash's keys will not change in future.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get what you want by using `Enumerable#each_with_object` and assigning a default value to the hash.

```
def group_search_results(items)
  results = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
  items.each_with_object(results) do |item|
    results[item['Type']] << {'title' => item['Title'], 'year' => item['Year']}
  end
end

describe "search_results" do
  it "groups into an object" do
    items = [
      {'Type' => 'movie', 'Title' => 'Thor', 'Year' => 2011},
      {'Type' => 'movie', 'Title' => 'Iron Man', 'Year' => 2008},
      {'Type' => 'series', 'Title' => 'Parks and Recreation', 'Year' => 2009},
      {'Type' => 'series', 'Title' => 'Friends', 'Year' => 1994},
    ]

    results = group_search_results(items)
    expect(results).to eq({
      'movie' => [
        {'title' => 'Thor', 'year' => 2011},
        {'title' => 'Iron Man', 'year' => 2008},
      ],
      'series' => [
        {'title' => 'Parks and Recreation', 'year' => 2009},
        {'title' => 'Friends', 'year' => 1994},
      ],
    })
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
results =  { 
  search: { 
    movie: [
      { title: 'Thor', year: 2011 },
      { title: 'Iron Man', year: 2008 },
    ],
    tv: [
      { title: 'Parks and Recreation', year: 2009 },
      { title: 'Friends', year: 1994 },
    ]
  }
}

@results = Hash.new{|k, v| k[v] = []}
results[:search].each do |type, array| 
  @results[type].push(*array) 
end

results[:search].each_with_object(Hash.new{|k, v| k[v] = []}) do |(type, array), hash| 
  hash[type].push(*array) 
end
```